# Gitlab git push failing with Vagrant-managed Virtualbox

Tags: git, virtualbox, vagrant, gitlab

I was able to setup Virtualbox with Gitlab using these instructions --> https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/wiki/VirtualBox-Image. The web interface works just fine and I have added my host public key and created a 'test' project. However, I am unable to push to my test repository since it asks for git@33.33.33.10's password after making a test directory and doing a 'git init'. I have added my key and the web interface works just fine. Any ideas what could be wrong?

```
$ git remote add test git@33.33.33.10:test.git
$ git push -u test master
git@33.33.33.10's password: ...
```

I've tried this as well with the same results ( 2222 VM-side equals 22 Host-side):

```
git remote add test ssh://git@localhost:2222/test.git
git push -u test master
git@localhost's password:...
```

Should not require a password. I have also added the 'vagrant' user to the 'git' group on the VM.

I've verified that on the VM I am able to correctly receive the expected results below:

```
vagrant@lucid32:~$ ssh -T git@localhost
hello rails, this is gitolite v2.2-11-g8c4d1aa running on git 1.7.0.4
the gitolite config gives you the following access:
     R   W  gitolite-admin
    @R_ @W_ testing
```

Here is my VagrantFile:

```
Vagrant::Config.run do |config|
config.vm.box = "gitlab"
config.vm.network :hostonly, "33.33.33.10"
end
```

This has something to do with remote git pushing to virtualbox. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I've tried to add Port 2222 to /etc/ssh/sshd_config and use port 2222 in config/gitlab.yml but to no avail. It is still asking for git@localhost's password when I try to push from the Host to the VM. Any ideas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a brand new install using the gitlabhq_install scripts not in a virtual machine and had the original same issue. I was able to create a project and add my key via the web interface but could not push at all to a test repo. So I added my user (not the gitlabhq user) public ssh key by running "ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub remote-host" and restarted ssh. I still got the same issue so I 'sudo vim /home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys' and manually copied my key that was added with the above command to between the '#gitolite start/end' tags. After resetting ssh only then was I able to finally push... now I am still scratching my head but at least it works I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I had some serious issues getting the vagrant machine up and running.  For one, it doesn't use the same defaults that the code expects (see #1).  It uses rvm (see #3)

1. The vagrant VM decides to use "vagrant" rather than "git" as the user.
   So your repo URL is really:
   ssh://**vagrant**@localhost:2222/test.git
2. I added a ~/.ssh/config (chmod 600):
   Host *
      User vagrant
      IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa`
3. If you get past this, you'll probably get an error about "/usr/bin/env ruby could not find file", since you are using vagrant, which uses rvm.
   I had to do these two things:

   - `env | grep -E "^(GEM_HOME|PATH|RUBY_VERSION|MY_RUBY_HOME|GEM_PATH)=" > ~/.ssh/environment`
   - and add  `PermitUserEnvironment yes` to sshd_config + restart
     https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-shell/issues/12

Answer (score 0):

it seems that your keys aren't sent to the virtual machine. Can you check that you have correct id_rsa and id_rsa.pub files in your users .ssh directory. This can be very problematic if you are running vagrant on windows (http://vagrantup.com/docs/getting-started/ssh.html)

Hope this will help.

Comment: Yes I've added my public ssh keys for my user on the host machine to the gitlab interface in the web browser. I am running Ubuntu for both host and vm,. I can ssh to the machine with my vagrant user just fine. On the virtual machine itself I cannot seem to push either... which is strange since gitolite is registered with gitlab as I can add keys and make new projects from within the web browser gitlab interface. However, if (as the user that runs gitlab) I try to git push from a test directory.. then I get`vagrant@lucid32:~/test2$ git push
W access for test2 DENIED to rails`. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem, while i was trying to push to gitlab.com:

```
git push gitlab mybranch
```

pushing happend with the following vagrant code

```
  config.vm.provision :shell, :name => "pushing to remote", :keep_color => true, :privileged => false, :inline => <<-SHELL
        ---snip---
        git push gitlab mybranch
        ---snip---
  SHELL
```

the following error occured:

```
==> default: GitLab: The project you were looking for could not be found.
==> default: fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
==> default:
==> default: Please make sure you have the correct access rights
==> default: and the repository exists.
```

my solution was to put the code which should be executed by vagrant in a shell script and call this with a privileged shell wrapped in a `su`

```
  config.vm.provision :shell, :name => "Workaround to run update-repo.sh as vagrant user", :keep_color => true, :privileged => true, :inline => <<-SHELL
    su - vagrant -c /home/vagrant/bin/push.sh
  SHELL
```